# How to convert a source code file into HTML?

Tags: filetype-html

I've a file of source code written in a programming language (e.g. PHP) and I would like to convert it into a HTML file, so I can publish it on web in order to share my code.

By conversion I mean, for example, converting new lines into `<br>` tags so that the text will keep the same formatting both in the text editor and in the web browser. Ideally it should also preserve syntax highlighting so it can be also printed.

Is this achievable in Vim? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by converting? What is expected output?

Comment: Expected output would be html (browser friendly format).

Comment: All text files are 'browser friendly'. But when I see [Alexander Myshov's answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/793/153) I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: I think a detail is missing from the question. Do you want to produce a full HTML document for each source file or just a fragment of HTML code you can embed in another document, or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following vim command would creates an html rendering of the current file.

```
:TOhtml
```

It saves the file in the same folder (with .html extension) and it will include styles, foreground/background colours and [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting), so the file can be straight web published as well as printed.

For more options (like adding line numbers, compability with old browsers, etc.), check: `:help TOhtml`.

To convert file non-interactively, try the following command:

```
vim -E -s -c "let g:html_no_progress=1" -c "syntax on" -c "set ft=c" -c "runtime syntax/2html.vim" -cwqa myfile.c
```

Related:

- [Convert codes to HTML with CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915547/convert-codes-to-html-with-css-style) at stackoverflow

Comment: You don't need the `%`, since that's the default. Also note that this is exactly the same as the other answer (`:runtime! syntax/2html.vim`), the only difference is that with `TOhtml` you can add easily a range (instead of setting `g:html_start_line` and `g:html_end_line` manually.

Comment: This doesn't work properly for me on Vim 8.2 (nonstandard file type, not C): `vim -E -s -c "let g:html_no_progress=1" -c "set background=light" -c "set ft=myfiletype" -c "runtime syntax/2html.vim" -c wqa myfile.txt`. Specifically, the syntax highlighting CSS rules don't get inserted into the resulting HTML file. If I remove the `-s` for silent mode, it works fine (but not sure if that would work properly without a tty).

Answer (score 6):

As I understood you, you want to convert content of current window to HTML.
Try to run this command:

```
:runtime! syntax/2html.vim
```

more info here:

```
:help convert-to-HTML
```