# How to print value of register to the standard output?

Tags: command-line, register, ex-mode

To print the whole buffer, you can use `%p`, how do I print value of register to the standard output?

Here is example how I would print the whole buffer:

```
$ ex +'norm dw' +'%p' -scq! <(echo foo bar)
bar
```

So I'm looking for `%p` equivalent printing way for registers, for example to print the last deletion (`""`).

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: For example I've many columns in the file, and I want to delete selected column using `ex` and print what was deleted.

Comment: E.g. This would remove 3rd column: `ex +'%norm 2WdW' '+%p' -scq! <(echo 1 2 3 4 5)` in shell, but I want opposite, to print what was actually deleted.

Comment: Why don't you use other tools like awk?

Comment: @romainl The `awk` is more [stream oriented](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2692/467), so there are some limitations in more complex parsing scenarios. On the other side awk is quicker, as I did some [benchmarking](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236525/21471) recently, but I want to learn ex/vi more efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echo command can print the value of any register:

```
:echon @"
```

This output can be redirected to the file (or standard output in this case) by using

```
:redir > file
:echon @"
:redir END
```

So the working example is as below:

```
$ ex +'norm dw' +'redir>>/dev/stdout|echon @-' -scq! <(echo foo bar)
foo
```

Where `@-` register stores the last text that you deleted or changed.

<sup>Note: The [`/dev/stdout`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) could not exist on some non-Unix systems.</sup>

Or workaround would be to replace the entire buffer with register and print it, like:

```
ex +'norm dw' +'%d|put-|%p' -scq! <(echo foo bar)
```